# Cryptsetup with dm-integrity - weird benchmark results

Tags: luks, cryptsetup, device-mapper, integrity

I'm benchmarking various `cryptsetup` volumes and I'm getting unexpected results on Debian.

I'm using numbers from [this talk](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/cryptsetup/) as a rough reference. One of the slides shows benchmark results for various configurations:

[image: A slide showing benchmarks for various configurations of cryptsetup, journaling reduces R/W throughput by about 40% in all configurations.]

My setup is not identical and I'm running all tests in VMs, so I don't expect results to be exactly identical, but I think they should roughly reflect what's on the slide. In particular I expect to see performance drop of about 35 for authenticated integrity modes (*AES-XTS,HMAC-SHA256*) compared to non-authenticated counterparts (*AES-XTS*) and then another 35% for journaled integrity vs. non-journaled integrity.

But here are my results, similar for Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Debian 10.4:

```
LUKS2 container:
    Capacity    1056964608 B
    Read        26.5MB/s
    Write       8855kB/s

LUKS2 with hmac-sha256, no journal:
    Capacity    1040322560 B
    Read        19.0MB/s
    Write       6352kB/s

LUKS2 with hmac-sha256, journaled:
    Capacity    1040322560 B
    Read        18.9MB/s
    Write       6311kB/s
```

About 30% performance drop after enabling integrity, that's expected. But then the difference between journaled and non-journaled integrity is marginal. I mean, that's much better than original benchmark so I should be happy, but how do I know that the journal is actually working and if it is, how do I opt out?

Here are my `cryptsetup` format commands:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sdb --sector-size 4096
cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sdb --sector-size 4096 --integrity hmac-sha256
cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sdb --sector-size 4096 --integrity hmac-sha256 --integrity-no-journal
```

Benchmark command:

```
fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=/dev/mapper/sdb --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75
```

VMs are configured on VirtualBox 6.1 with settings default for Debian or Ubuntu respectively. Disks are 1 GB VDIs, fixed size and pre-filled with zeros, host buffering disabled. Underlying SSD is using 4k sectors, hence `--sector-size 4096`.

Interestingly, both the basic `--integrity` variant and the `--integrity-no-journal` one create intermediate `sdb_dif` mapped device with journal and both `sdb` devices have identical size:

```
$ sudo integritysetup status /dev/mapper/sdb_dif
/dev/mapper/sdb_dif is active and is in use.
  type:    INTEGRITY
  tag size: 32
  integrity: (none)
  device:  /dev/sdb
  sector size:  4096 bytes
  interleave sectors: 32768
  size:    2031880 sectors
  mode:    read/write
  failures: 0
  journal size: 8380416 bytes
  journal watermark: 50%
  journal commit time: 10000 ms

$ sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/sdb
1040322560
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of answer:

`cryptsetup format` **ignores** the `--integrity-no-journal` flag.

Instead, your options are:

- At each `open`, always provide `--integrity-no-journal`.
- At your first open (i.e. when formatting the inner device with a filesystem, or to add the inner device to an MD RAID), provide `--persistent --integrity-no-journal` to persist the `--integrity-no-journal` setting.  Then future `open` will not need the flag.  This option only works with `cryptsetup`, not if you are using direct `integritysetup`.
- While the device is already `open`ed, issue a `refresh --persistent --integrity-no-journal`.  This option only works with `cryptsetup`, not if you are using direct `integritysetup`.

---

Old text:

Did you provide the `--integrity-no-journal` flag to `integritysetup open`?  It looks like `dm-integrity` does **not** save the (non-)existence of a journal in the superblock when you format.

I formatted a USB 2.0 flash disk partition with `integritysetup format /dev/sdb1 --no-wipe`.

Then I opened it with `integritysetup open /dev/sdb1 int-sdb1`, and did `sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; dd count=16384 bs=4096 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/int-sdb1`.  This consistently gave me results of between 2.1Mb/s to 2.4Mb/s.

I closed it and then reopened with `integritysetup open /dev/sdb1 int-sdb1 --integrity-no-journal`, and issued the same `dd` command.  This time it gave me from between 4.0Mb/s to 7.0Mb/s, a marked improvement.  The massive variance might be due to the flash translation layer; it's a lousy throwaway cheap disk.

I repeated this again with `integritysetup format /dev/sdb1 --no-wipe --integrity-no-journal`.  Again, what matters is wheter you gave `--integrity-no-journal` to the **`open`** command, *not* to the **`format`** command.

So it might be a non-clarity of `integritysetup`.  If you gave `--integrity-no=journal` to the `format` command.

Comment: I was using `cryptsetup` rather than `integritysetup`, but it also has the `--integrity-no-journal` option, so that could be the cause I guess. I wonder why it accepts this option when formatting too if the produced container still works with journal? Maybe it's flagged as ready for journal-less usage? I'll test this on the next occasion. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `man cryptsetup` on my system claims that for LUKS2 containers the setting *can* be persisted, but I'm not sure if it gets persisted at `format` time; the manual only mentions persisting in the `open` and `refresh` commands.

Comment: Also note that this persisting might only work for LUKS2 specifically, not LUKS1, so that may actually come into play here.

Comment: I tried again with `cryptsetup` this time.

case 1: format without `--integrity-no-journal`, open without special parameters: `dd` is around 1 MiB/s

case 2: `format --integrity-no-journal`, open without special parameters: `dd` is around 1MiB/s

case 3: `format --integrity-no-journal`, open without special parameters, `refresh --integrity-no-journal`: `dd` is around 4 to 6MB/s

So it looks awefully, awefully like `format` **accepts** but **ignores** `--integrity-no-journal` --- what an awful interface.

Comment: You can `--persistent` to either `open` or `refresh` in order to persist the `--integrity-no-journal` flag, but you can't give it to `format`.  So if you are going to format the device with a filesystem or put it in a RAID afterwards, you would `open` it anyway and you should probably give `--persistent --inegrity-no-journal` on the first open as well.  Then future `open` will not need the flag.

Comment: Sounds like you've solved my problem :) Could you move all this info form comments to the answer?

Comment: raid5atemyhomework: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/448881/raid5atemyhomework and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/448994/raid5atemyhomework.  You’ll then be able to [edit] and continue commenting on this answer.